# Python.Столкновение двух объектов в pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Как мне в моем коде реализовать столкновение?

```
import pygame
window=pygame.display.set_mode((700, 700))
pygame.display.set_caption('PYWINDOW')
screen=pygame.Surface((700, 700))
run=True
class Ball():
    def __init__(self, speed, width, height, oX, oY, img):
        self.speed=speed
        self.width=width
        self.height=height
        self.reverseX=False
        self.reverseY=False
        self.height=height
        self.x=oX
        self.y=oY
        self.img=img
    def drawAndMove(self, holst):
        # oX
        if self.reverseX:
            if self.x>0:
                self.x-=0.9*self.speed
            else:
                self.reverseX=False
        elif self.x<700-self.width:
            self.x+=1.3*self.speed
        else:
            self.reverseX=True
        # oY
        if self.reverseY:
            if self.y>0:
                self.y-=0.8*self.speed
            else:
                self.reverseY=False
        elif self.y<700-self.height:
            self.y+=1.1*self.speed
        else:
            self.reverseY=True
        holst.blit(self.img, (self.x, self.y))



def isQuit():
    global run
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run=False

    
bimg=pygame.image.load('/home/korobeinikovi/ball.png')

ball1=Ball(1, 48, 46, 100, 100, bimg)
ball2=Ball(1, 48, 46, 100, 150, bimg)
while run:
    screen.fill((0, 100, 0))
    ball1.drawAndMove(screen)
    ball2.drawAndMove(screen)
    window.blit(screen, (0, 0))
    isQuit()
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Что конкретно не получается? Приведите ваши попытки и возникающие проблемы

Comment: @dlm0m есть ли в pygame функция которая обрабатывает столкновения для спрайтов?

Comment: Не знаю. Можно независимо от используемой библиотеки проверять пересечение двух фигур. Например, для пересечения двух точек надо проверить равенство их координат и т.п.

Comment: @dIm0n Я тоже хотел так сделать но это будет работать не для всех сторон спрайта

Comment: Обычно используют т.н. хитбоксы, т.е. не проверяется пересечение каких-то сложных фигур, а проверяется пересечение включающих их прямоугольников

Comment: В PyGame есть функции обработки столкновений спрайтов,- без этого PyGame нельзя было бы считать полноценным модулем для создания игр.

Comment: @Assur а какие конкретно?

Comment: Например, spritecollide

Comment: @Igorok в документации написано, что сравниваются прямоугольники или окружности, так что "не для всех сторон спрайта" остаётся в силе https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide

Comment: Посмотрите: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1150571/201445

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы вам предложил отрисовывать шар не как `width` и `height`, а также `oX` и `oY`, а как Радиус и центр шара. А именно а также `R` , `oX` и `oY`. Это даст вам проще проводить сравнение для столкновений, а именно:

Столкновение двух шаров есть их соприкосновение, при котором расстояние между ними равно 0. То есть, когда они сталкиваются, расстояние между их центрами равняется сумме их радиусов `R`. Расстояние между двумя точками на плоскости вычисляется по формуле (перевожу на путхон):

```
import math
distance = math.sqrt( (ball1.oX - ball2.oX) ** 2 +  (ball1.oY - ball2.oY) ** 2 )
```

Далее мы сравниваем, если `distance == ball1.R + ball2.R`, значит они столкнулись. Но может быть такое, что наши шарики из-за чего-то пройдут чуть-чуть сквозь друг друга, а значит, наша формула не сработает, поэтому предлагаю поставить `distance <= ball1.R + ball2.R`.

В итоге заносим в общий цикл для проверки:

```
while Run:
    ...
    distance = math.sqrt( (ball1.oX - ball2.oX) ** 2 +  (ball1.oY - ball2.oY) ** 2 )
    if distance <= ball1.R + ball2.R:
        function_of_collision_you_need()
```

---

Всем добра-бобра

Comment: Если объекты оформить как спрайты, то можно использовать `pygame.sprite.collide_circle`, пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1150571/201445

Comment: Тем более. Просто описал это математически за незнанием NumPy